# How do I set different action by $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] from different submit button?

Tags: php, form-submit

Consider that I've Two forms in file:

```
<form method="post" name=frm1 action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<input type=submit>
</form>

<form method="post" name=frm2 action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

And two PHP scripts in same file:

```
<?php
//To be executed by submitting form:frm1
>?

<?php
//To be executed by submitting form:frm2
>?
```

Now How do I set execution of particular PHP script by means of particular submit button of corresponding form (`frm1`/`frm2`)?

I don't what to do in advance with `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`.

---

**Another(Alternative) case** is: Consider I've two submit button within a (single) form:

```
<form method="post" name=frm action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<input type=button value=submit1 onclick=submit()>
<input type=button value=submit2 onclick=submit()>
</form>
```

And PHP scripts for execution:

```
<?php
//To be executed by clicking button:submit1
>?

<?php
//To be executed by clicking button:submit2
>?
```

Here How can I set particular execution by particular button for submit?

---

What logical condition/validation can I use & where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just assign a name attribute to the submit button and then check in the script which form it is, like this:

```
<input name="form1" type=submit>
```

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["form1"])) {
        echo "first form";
    }

?>
```

**EDIT:**

If have have 2 submit buttons for one form. Also just give them name attributes like: `form1-1` or `form1-2`.